# Object modifiers in python, is it possible?

Tags: python, modifiers

Is there a way to create object modifiers coding in python, similarly to what can be done for addons, or the only way is writing C/C++ modules and rebuild Blender from source code?

Comment: You can make Geonodes that act as modifiers, which themselves can be made using Python. But AFAIK the Python API doesn't provide anything to create new modifiers.